# What font is this in the image?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Sorry for the lame question, but I can't figure out what font is used in image below?

[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Myriad:

http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/myriad/semibold/